# Tag rows based on other columns values

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
street_name        eircode
Malborough Road    BLT12
123 Fake Road      NaN
My Street          NaN
```

I would like to create another column called **unique** based on these conditions:

1. If it has eircode, return 'yes' in the **unique** column, THEN
2. If it doesn't have an eircode, check the first string in the **street_name**:

   - if the first string is a digit, return 'yes' in the **unique** column
   - if it is not, return 'no' in the **unique** column

I came up with this solution where:

1. I changed the data types to string for both columns **street_name** and **eircode**
2. Get the first string using a lambda function
3. Defined a tagging function to be applied to the data frame

`# change data types

df['eircode'] = df['eircode'].astype('str')
df['street_name'] = df['street_name'].astype('str')`

`# get the first string from street_name column 
df['first_str'] = df['street_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])`

```
def tagging(x):
if x['eircode'] != 'nan':
    return 'yes'
elif x['first_str'].isdigit() == True:
    return 'yes'
else:
    return 'no'

df['unique'] = df.apply(tagging, axis=1)
```

The issue with this is that I have to change the data type and then have to make separate column. Is there a more elegant way or a more concise way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply those separate conditions using the `|` operator, then map the resulting Boolean array to `yes` and `no`. The first condition just looks wether `eircode` is null, and the second uses a regex to check that `street_name` starts with a digit:

```
df['unique'] = ((~df.eircode.isnull()) | (df.street_name.str.match('^[0-9]'))).map({True:'yes',False:'no'})
>>> df
       street_name eircode unique
0  Malborough Road   BLT12    yes
1    123 Fake Road     NaN    yes
2        My Street     NaN     no
```

Comment: Accepted this as an answer because the use of regex will evaluate any numbers and won't throw an error even if the number is a float type.

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas, it's best to use column-wise calculations; `apply` with a custom function represents an inefficient, Python-level row-wise loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'street_name': ['Malborough Road', '123 Fake Road', 'My Street'],
                   'eircode': ['BLT12', None, None]})

cond1 = df['eircode'].isnull()
cond2 = ~df['street_name'].str.split(n=1).str[0].str.isdigit()

df['unique'] = np.where(cond1 & cond2, 'no', 'yes')

print(df)

  eircode      street_name unique
0   BLT12  Malborough Road    yes
1    None    123 Fake Road    yes
2    None        My Street     no
```

Comment: code for cond2 is excellent as I was trying to do the same (Selecting the first word after the split) but did not know the correct way to do it. great use of np.where which I've never used before. one issue I encountered using this solution is that when the number extracted is a float it will return an error.